# Does Spark Streaming supports iterations as Flink?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink

For example, here is program of Flink that continuously subtracts 1 from a series of integers until they reach zero: 
[Flink iterations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html#iterations)

```java
DataStream<Long> someIntegers = env.generateSequence(0, 1000);

IterativeStream<Long> iteration = someIntegers.iterate();

DataStream<Long> minusOne = iteration.map(new MapFunction<Long, Long>() {
  @Override
  public Long map(Long value) throws Exception {
    return value - 1 ;
  }
});

DataStream<Long> stillGreaterThanZero = minusOne.filter(new FilterFunction<Long>() {
  @Override
  public boolean filter(Long value) throws Exception {
    return (value > 0);
 }
});

iteration.closeWith(stillGreaterThanZero);

DataStream<Long> lessThanZero = minusOne.filter(new FilterFunction<Long>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Long value) throws Exception {
       return (value <= 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from writing your own. I'd write a tail recursive function that runs on the driver and does all you want. The context can be any kind of object that maintains state or whatever you want to take decisions.

```
@tailrec
def iterateWhileYouCan[T](data: RDD[T], context: Boolean):RDD[T] = {
    if (context)
      data
    iterateWhileYouCan(awesomeComputation(data), context)
  }
```